# Add indent(margin|padding) between content and scroll in overflow: auto block only if its overflowed

Tags: html, css, scroll, overflow

i have list with a previously unknown number of elements

i need to apply padding between scroll and content **only if list is overflown**

###### html

```
    <div class="list">
      <div class="item">1</div>         
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>          
    </div>
```

###### css

```
  .list {
     padding-right: 10px // i need apply this only if scroll apeared
     max-height: 40px
     overflow: auto
  }
```

Comment: what are you looking to achieve, describe your goal instead

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if that's possible with CSS, but you can do it with JS, checking it like `element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight`.

For example:

```js
const listElement = document.querySelector('.list');

//OR window.addEventListener('resize', () => applyStylesToList());
new ResizeObserver(() => applyStylesToList).observe(listElement);

applyStylesToList();

function applyStylesToList() {
  const hasScroll = isScrollbarVisible(listElement);
  listElement.style.paddingRight = hasScroll ? '10px' : '0';
}

function isScrollbarVisible(element) {
  return element.scrollHeight > element.clientHeight;
}
```

```css
.list {
   max-height: 40px;
   overflow: scroll;
}
```

```html
  <div class="list">
    <div class="item">item</div>   
    <div class="item">item</div>
    <div class="item">item</div>
  </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I was able to get the padding to show after a 3rd div is entered into your list. It does require some vanilla JavaScript to do it this way though. Hope this helps!

```js
let list = document.querySelector(".list");

function moreThan() {
  if (list.childElementCount >= 3) {
    list.style.paddingRight = "10px";
  }
}

list.addEventListener("overflow", moreThan());
```

```css
.list {
  /* padding-right: 10px; */
  max-height: 40px;
  overflow: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
      <div class="item">1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
      <div class="item">many items or 1</div>
    </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

based on Telman's answer i build this List react component

##### list.tsx

```
import s from './list.module.scss'
import { FC, useRef } from 'react'
import { useIsOverflowed } from '../../../hooks/dom/use-is-overflowed'

type Props = {
   variant?: 'dark' | 'white'
   className?: string
   scrollPadding?: number
}


export const List: FC<Props> = ({ scrollPadding = 13, variant = 'white', 
className, children }) => {
const ref = useRef<HTMLDivElement>(null)
const hasScroll = useIsOverflowed(ref)

return (
  <div
    ref={ref}
    style={{
      paddingRight: hasScroll ? scrollPadding : 0
    }}
    className={`${s.wrapper} ${className} ${s[variant]}`}
  >
    {children}
  </div>
)}
```

##### use-is-overflowed.ts

```
import { RefObject, useEffect, useState } from 'react'

export const useIsOverflowed = <T extends HTMLElement>(ref: RefObject<T>) 
=> {
const [isOverflowed, setIsOverflowed] = useState(false)

useEffect(() => {
  const resizeObserver = new ResizeObserver(([entry]) => {
    setIsOverflowed(entry.target.scrollHeight > entry.target.clientHeight)
  })

  resizeObserver.observe(ref.current as Element)

  return () => resizeObserver.disconnect()
  }, [])

  return isOverflowed  }
```